# Datastore Index Not working for property that is JSON string

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

The following query in Datastore return the expected number of results:

```
SELECT timestamp from leadgenie_campaign_model_dev where campaign = "3667f39d-a3ff-4acb-b1ca-6f730bbc7989"
```

This query is backed by an index, which allows for the projection.

But this one doesn't return any results, despite the fact that an index also exists. `attrs` is a JSON string

```
SELECT timestamp, attrs from leadgenie_campaign_model_dev where campaign = "3667f39d-a3ff-4acb-b1ca-6f730bbc7989"
```

Here's the spec for the indexes:

```
indexes:

- kind: leadgenie_campaign_model_dev
  properties:
  - name: campaign
  - name: attrs
  - name: timestamp

- kind: leadgenie_campaign_model_dev
  properties:
  - name: campaign
  - name: timestamp
  - name: attrs

- kind: leadgenie_campaign_model_dev
  properties:
  - name: campaign
  - name: timestamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to include the subproperty in the query, after creating an index for those properties specifically.

```
SELECT timestamp, attrs.score, attrs.sz from leadgenie_campaign_model_dev where campaign = "3667f39d-a3ff-4acb-b1ca-6f730bbc7989"
```

```
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: leadgenie_campaign_model_dev
  properties:
  - name: campaign
  - name: attrs.score
  - name: attrs.sz
  - name: timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your attrs field more than 1,500 bytes by any chance? That is a limit for a string property to be indexed. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits .

Comment: Seems like most entries are under 100 bytes. Def good to know though.

Comment: Another possibility is that the attrs property itself is not indexed. It might be worth reindexing all entities for a given campaign and then see if it works.